# Why is my Svelte component not being rerendered despite passing in new prop values?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have two Svelte components, a Parent and a Child. The Parent has an item. The Child has a button. When you click the Child button, the click handler should toggle a boolean in the Parent's item.

I expected the Child to be re-rendered because I passed it a new value. I want the text label on the button to toggle between "open" and "close".

What actually happens is nothing.

```
<script>
// Parent.svelte

import Child from "./Child.svelte";

let item = {id: 1, open: false};

function onToggle(e) {
    item = {...item, open: !(item.open)};
    console.log("onToggle:", item);
}
console.log("Parent:", item);
</script>

<Child
  open={console.log("Child prop:", item), item.open}
  onToggle={onToggle} />
```

```
<script>
export let open = false;
export let onToggle = null;

let buttonLabel = "open";
if (open) {
    buttonLabel = "close";
}

console.log(`Child: open=${open}; buttonLabel=${buttonLabel}`);
</script>

<button on:click={onToggle}>{buttonLabel}</button>
```

After clicking the button a few times this is what I see. It seems like `item.open` is being toggled, but Child isn't being re-rendered with the new value.

```
"Parent:" { id: 1 ,open: false }
"Child prop:" { id: 1 ,open: false }
"Child: open=false; buttonLabel=open"
"onToggle:" { id: 1 ,open: true }
"Child prop:" { id: 1 ,open: true }
"onToggle:" { id: 1 ,open: false }
"Child prop:" { id: 1 ,open: false }
```

Also, for the sake of simplicity, in this example the Parent only has a single item defined, but the code I'm working on has an array of items.

Comment: console.log returns a value. By using && between console.log and open you pass true everytime. Use the comma operator instead. Please let me know if this fixes your issue so that this could make into an answer.

Comment: Thanks, replaced `&&` with `,`. Unfortunately, this didn't affect the behavior. The Child component is still not rendered.

Comment: Also, wait. Makes sense why the behavior didn't change. Even if `console.log` returned `true` every time, `open` would still be `false`. `true && false == false`. :)

Comment: Ah, wait some more. Apparently, ^^^ my previous comment is not how things work. @Corri's answer works only if I change `&&` to `,`.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you might also want to have a look at https://svelte.dev/tutorial/event-forwarding Here passing `onToggle` as prop could be avoided by leaving just `on:click` on the button and setting `on:click={onToggle}` on the component and the prop could also be changed directly `item.open = !item.open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [$: marks a statement as reactive](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive) section in the docs and these tutorial sessions [#1](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations) [#2](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-statements)

```
<script>
export let open = false;
export let onToggle = null;

$: buttonLabel = open ? "close" : "open"

$: console.log(`Child: open=${open}; buttonLabel=${buttonLabel}`)
    
</script>

{open}
<button on:click={onToggle}>{buttonLabel}</button>
```

(works without the log on the component... don't think it's a good idea to put it there)

Comment: Ah, ok! I was missing a `$:` and also the logging did mess me up. This answer works with the logging in the component prop if I change `&&` to `,`. Thanks!